# Including script from one website to another

Tags: php, include

I have built a script for purchasing simple cards for people on their website.

I want it so that the code does not need to be on their server so they can see it and just copy it and stop paying me for the code. I need to know how to do this!

Explained further:
1) I have a website (mine) that is ex. www.website1.com/script/index.php (this is the card script)
2) I want to implement it to a clients website ex. www.website-client.com/buy-a-card.php (this is where I want my script to be displayed on their website)

PS. I have tried php include function, it did not work.

How do I do this without letting them see the code and accessing it to change it, stop payments to me for the code, etc.

Thanks,
Chad.

Comment: Sell it with a suited licence, so that if they give it to any third party without your consent you can sue them. Code obfuscation, while achievable, can be nullified and become useless

Comment: That's a very good point, I guess I could make a PHP script which includes a license number and I have all the license numbers which are very unique (and not guessable) and I have a database with the licenses and if the license number isn't in my database then the script is not executable. Is this what you meant?

Comment: No. I mean, clients buy the script signing an agreement to not disclose your code to anyone, nor modify it, and use it only on their application. If they don't do that (resell your software, publish it, modify it, and so on) they can be sued. Of course, you need to be prepared with an army of lawyers if you really want to enforce that. But your idea could also work (it's the "activation code" kind of thing), but I don't think it will be easy to implement (or to avoid it being bypassed)

Comment: Or implement both of them at the same time, so that there is one (basic not too much code) but if they bypass it, you can sue.

Comment: Is there anyone who knows how to do what I mentioned above? About the SCRIPT that only allows people with licenses to use the code on their website. What I'm guessing I want is something that when it is outputted it searches my website for the domain name or a unique license id for each client. IF it returns false, then the script does not work.. the only thing is.. I don't want them to be able to remove this "check for license" script inside the script and hence be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have them include an iframe pointing to your script, have them redirect to your script from their site, or have them post to your script for processing.

The iframe would be the easiest to get started, but you'll need a way for them to transfer data to your script if you're passing more than what a querystring will allow.

Comment: I am using this as of now, but PayPal Payments doesn't allow their processor to be inside an iframe, therefore, when you go to pay, it opens a new tab which you pay in. When the payment is complete, it goes back to my site's payment success file (ex. www.website1.com/script/payment-success.php) and doesn't load that into the iframe of the clients website.